# fc-cache can't find texlive fonts on a no-root Ubuntu server

Tags: fonts

I have to use LaTeX on a Ubuntu server without root. I did the things below:

1. I download the texlive.iso and extract it into a folder. (I can't mount the iso file without )
2. I run `chmod +x install-tl && ./install_tl` to install texlive. (I changed the TEXMF-DIR to `~/texlive/2023`, my home dir is `/share/userfile/<username>`.)
3. After installing, I add paths in `~/.zshrc`. `tex -v` gives right output.
4. I copied `~/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` to `~/.fonts/09-texlive.conf`
5. I run `fc-cache -fv` to refresh the cache.

However, I didn't find any folder with `texlive` in the output of `fc-cache -fv` and `fc-list`, also the folders of texlive fonts weren't in `fc-conflist`.

What happened?

```
% fc-conflist
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-antialias.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-hinting-slight.conf: 设置微调风格为“轻微 (hintslight)”
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/10-scale-bitmap-fonts.conf: 位图缩放
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/11-lcdfilter-default.conf: 将 lcddefault 设为默认 LCD 滤镜
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-sans-mono.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-sans.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-lgc-serif.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans-mono.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-sans.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-dejavu-serif.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/20-unhint-small-vera.conf: 为大小小于 8ppem 的 Bitstream Vera 字体禁用微调
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/25-arphic-ukai-render.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/25-arphic-uming-render.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/30-cjk-aliases.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/30-metric-aliases.conf: 为相似或规格兼容的字体家族设置替换
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/30-opensymbol.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/35-arphic-ukai-aliases.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/35-arphic-uming-aliases.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/40-nonlatin.conf: 为非拉丁语言字体设置替换
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/41-arphic-ukai.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/41-arphic-uming.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-generic.conf: 为绘文字 (Emoji) 或数学字体设置替换
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/45-latin.conf: 为拉丁语言字体设置替换
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/49-sansserif.conf: 在没有通用名称时添加 sans-serif 到字体家族
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf: 载入用户自定义文件
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/51-local.conf: 载入本地自定义文件
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/56-language-selector-ar.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-sans-mono.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-sans.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/57-dejavu-serif.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/58-dejavu-lgc-sans-mono.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/58-dejavu-lgc-sans.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/58-dejavu-lgc-serif.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/59-lohit-devanagari.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-generic.conf: 设置首选绘文字 (Emoji) 或数学字体
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/60-latin.conf: 设置首选拉丁语言字体
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-bookman.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-c059.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-d050000l.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-fallback-backwards.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-fallback-generics.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-gothic.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-nimbus-mono-ps.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-nimbus-roman.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-nimbus-sans.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-p052.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-standard-symbols-ps.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/61-urw-z003.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-01-tlwg-kinnari.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-02-tlwg-norasi.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-10-tlwg-loma.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-11-tlwg-waree.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-13-tlwg-garuda.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-14-tlwg-umpush.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-15-laksaman.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-21-tlwg-typo.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-22-tlwg-typist.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-23-tlwg-mono.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/64-language-selector-prefer.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-beng-extra.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-deva-extra.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-gubbi.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-gujr-extra.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-guru-extra.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-orya-extra.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-pagul.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-fonts-telu-extra.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-smc-meera.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-0-smc-rachana.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-droid-sans-fallback.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-arphic-ukai.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-arphic-uming.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-fonts-persian.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-khmer.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/65-nonlatin.conf: 设置首选非拉丁语言字体
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-assamese.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-bengali.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-devanagari.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-gujarati.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-gurmukhi.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-kannada.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-odia.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-tamil-classical.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-tamil.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/66-lohit-telugu.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-fonts-smc-manjari.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-anjalioldlipi.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-chilanka.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-dyuthi.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-karumbi.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-keraleeyam.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-raghumalayalamsans.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-suruma.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/67-smc-uroob.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-ja.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-zh-cn.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-zh-hk.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-zh-mo.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-zh-sg.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-language-selector-zh-tw.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/69-unifont.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-fonts-noto-cjk.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/70-no-bitmaps.conf: 排除点阵字体
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/75-arphic-ukai-select.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/80-delicious.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-garuda-synthetic.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-kinnari-synthetic.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-laksaman-synthetic.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/89-tlwg-umpush-synthetic.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/90-arphic-ukai-embolden.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/90-arphic-uming-embolden.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/90-synthetic.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/conf.d/99-language-selector-zh.conf: 无描述
+ /etc/fonts/fonts.conf: Default configuration file
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-autohint.conf: 启用自动微调
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-full.conf: 设置微调风格为“完全 (hintfull)”
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-medium.conf: 设置微调风格为“中等 (hintmedium)”
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-hinting-none.conf: 设置微调风格为“无 (hintnone)”
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-no-sub-pixel.conf: 禁用次像素渲染
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-bgr.conf: 启用蓝绿红 (BGR) 像素布局的次像素渲染
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf: 启用红绿蓝 (RGB) 像素布局的次像素渲染
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-vbgr.conf: 启用垂直蓝绿红 (BGR) 像素布局的次像素渲染
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-vrgb.conf: 启用垂直红绿蓝 (RGB) 像素布局的次像素渲染
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-unhinted.conf: 禁用微调
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-legacy.conf: 将 lcdlegacy 设为默认 LCD 滤镜
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/11-lcdfilter-light.conf: 将 lcdlight 设为默认 LCD 滤镜
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/25-arphic-uming-bitmaps.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/25-ttf-arphic-ukai-render.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/25-unhint-nonlatin.conf: 为中日韩 (CJK) 字体禁用微调
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/30-droid-noto-mono.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/35-ttf-arphic-ukai-aliases.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/41-ttf-arphic-ukai.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/53-monospace-lcd-filter.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/64-arphic-uming.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/65-khmer.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/67-lohit-malayalam.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-force-bitmaps.conf: 接受点阵字体
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/70-yes-bitmaps.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/75-ttf-arphic-ukai-select.conf: 无描述
- /etc/fonts/conf.avail/90-ttf-arphic-ukai-embolden.conf: 无描述
```

Comment: Did the `~/.fonts` folder already exist? Maybe try with `~/.local/share/fonts/`.

Comment: Because `~/.fonts` is generally outdated. Furthermore, afterwards try to restart the Xserver.

Comment: @lukeflo I manually create the `~/.fonts` folder. I put that `.conf `file into ~/.local/share/fonts`, but nothing happens.

Comment: I put the `conf` file into `~/.config/fontconfig/`, and renamed it to `fonts.conf`, it worked. Why the previous method didn't work?

Comment: I probably find where the problem is. I've read the arch wiki of fontconfig: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Font_configuration#Fontconfig_configuration, and I put the `09-texlive.conf` into `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d`, things worked :)

Comment: There you go. I'm also using an Arch based distro and the wiki is the best. Don't know if there are other methods under Ubuntu. I just saw `sudo dpkg-reconfigure fontconfig` to update fontconfig, but you need root privileges. At least it works properly. For next time: I guess a problem like that would fit better to Unix/Linux.SE. There are far more experts for stuff like that ;)

Comment: I think where to post it is in a grey area, really @lukeflo. There are some TL-specific considerations involved, but, as you say, there are also issues which are more platform-oritentated.

Comment: @cfr, that's right. Its related to both forums. But especially the question of the correct `path` on a Linux server without root permissions I rather would post in the Unix/Linux.SE. But that's a personal preference and was not meant to criticise the OP's decision. Since many of the TeX vets also run Unix, one can find the proper solution here too.